# Is it possible to filter pact broker overview page/verification overview by tag?

Tags: pact

The pact broker overview page (the index page) displays the verification status of each pact which is very useful. Is it possible to filter this view, by a query parameter or such, so that I can see the verifications for a certain tag? I would like to use this to have an overview of all the prod-tagged pacts and their verifications to make sure that all prod-pacts have been verified when making releases of components.

If not I'm contemplating having a separate pact broker instance for the prod pacts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's totally doable. It's just a matter me (or someone else) having the time to do it. I've raised an issue for it here:

https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/issues/146

In the meantime, you can make your own "dashboard" by making a CI build for each prod tag. I think I may have put this on the gitter channel already.

Call `/pacts/provider/PROVIDER/consumer/CONSUMER/latest/prod`. Follow the `pb:consumer-version` relation, then follow the `pb:latest-verification-results-where-pacticipant-is-consumer` relation.

You'll get this.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "providerSummary": {
    "successful": [
      "B"
    ],
    "failed": [],
    "unknown": []
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "verificationResults": [
      {
        "providerName": "B",
        "providerApplicationVersion": "2",
        "success": true,
        "verificationDate": "2017-10-09T12:34:17+08:00",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "title": "Verification result",
            "name": "Verification result 2 for Pact between A (v1) and B",
            "href": "http://localhost:9292/pacts/provider/B/consumer/A/pact-version/7954fb780aa0db0ea451db4c3c1012fb7f0e1eb4/verification-results/2"
          },
          "pb:pact-version": {
            "title": "Pact",
            "name": "Pact between A (v1) and B",
            "href": "http://localhost:9292/pacts/provider/B/consumer/A/version/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:9292/verification-results/consumer/A/version/1/latest",
      "title": "Latest verification results for consumer A version 1"
    }
  }
}
```

I'll try and prioritise adding the tagged pacts to the UI.

Comment: As mentioned on gitter, I'm putting out a beta for this. To enable the prod pacts to be shown, add `showProdPacts=true` to the index URL. I'd appreciate your feedback on the implementation of this feature.

Comment: I've upgraded to the latest version but did not see that this worked. Is this beta feature on a branch?

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/UI-Documentation#index